# How to turn off the automatic alignment to cell borders in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

In microsoft excel, the page border always automatically stick to the border of cells.

I don't know how to exactly phrase this phenomena. We know that the area in which we are able to view the data has a top border and a left border. However I scroll horizontally or vertically, these two borders always find themselves a cell border and moves the whole view so that the borders overlap.

When there are large cells where the cell height is larger than the page height, then I could only see this cell instead of being able to view two cells at the same time. What could I do about this? Could I turn off this automatic aligning?

Comment: Your versions of Excel doesn't do what you want; the only way to get smooth scrolling is to upgrade to Excel 365. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/move-or-scroll-through-a-worksheet-06fc34b8-64bb-4d78-9b62-34656d700f82#:~:text=data%2C%20you%20can-,scroll%20smoothly,-through%20a%20worksheet

Comment: Did you try to lock the cells?